# save information in 2 tables whith one to one relation ship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 table the first table user and the second technicien and the relation is one to one relation ship i like inserte the information of the user and the information of technicien in the same time

user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
public function technicien()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\technicien');

}

use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'password','nom','prenom','tel','mobil','role',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

technicien model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class technicien extends Model
{

    public function zoneintervention()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\zoneintervention','technicien_zone','technicien_id','zoneintervention_id');

}
    public function metier()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\metier','technicien_metier','technicien_id','metier_id');

}
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

 public function tarificationtache()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tarificationtache::class);
}

}
```

this is the view create.blade.php

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@section('content')
@if(count($errors))

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
 <ul>
    @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
     <li>{{$message}}</li>
        @endforeach
 </ul>
</div>
@endif
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action=" {{url ('technicien')  }}" method="post">
         {{csrf_field()}}


        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Nom</label>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" 
 value="{{ old('nom') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('nom'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('nom') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Prenom</label>
                <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="prenom" value="{{ old('prenom') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('prenom'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('prenom') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Telephone</label>
                <input id="telephone" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="telephone" value="{{ old('telephone') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('telephone'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('telephone') 
  }}</strong>
                                 </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Mobile</label>
                <input id="Mobile" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="Mobile" value="{{ old('Mobile') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('Mobile'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('Mobile') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Role</label>
                <input id="role" type="text" class="form-control" 
  name="role" value="{{ old('role') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('role'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('role') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>

             <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : 
 '' }}">
                <label for="">E-Mail Address</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" 
  name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="password">Password</label>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="password" type="password" 
  class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}" 
  required 
  autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}
   </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="password_confirmation" 
    type="password_" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" 
    value="{{ 
    old('password_confirmation') }}" required s>
                        </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="zoneintervention">zoneintervention</label>


                <select multiple name="zoneintervention_id[]" 
     id="zoneintervention" class="form-control" >

                        @foreach($zoneintervention as $zoneintervention)
                         <option value="{{ $zoneintervention->id }}">
                            {{$zoneintervention->code_postal}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Moyenne Avis</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="moyenne_avis" class="form-
    control"value="{{old('moyenne_avis')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Etat</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="actif" class="form-
    control"value="{{old('actif')}}">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-
 control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>




@endsection
```

some one help me

Comment: Do not put all your code in the question. No one will read it and hence you won't get help

Comment: Something is wrong with the formatting. Could you fix this? Also: Try to keep the code minimal and cut it down to the essentials. That will greatly improve your odds of someone helping you.